# OpenERP 7 custom Purchase Order rule

Tags: python, postgresql, openerp-7

My target is to add Purchase order rule to only show purchase order created by the current user in selected user group.
I tried to apply this rule:

```
['|',('order_id.user_id','=',user.id),('order_id.user_id','=',False)]
```

But when try to view the Purchase orders it gives me the following error.

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1051, in search_read
    return self.do_search_read(req, model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1074, in do_search_read
    req.context)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2372, in search
    return self._search(cr, user, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, context=context, count=count)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4936, in _search
    self._apply_ir_rules(cr, user, query, 'read', context=context)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4816, in _apply_ir_rules
    rule_where_clause, rule_where_clause_params, rule_tables = rule_obj.domain_get(cr, uid, self._name, mode, context=context)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_rule.py", line 156, in domain_get
    query = self.pool.get(model_name)._where_calc(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, dom, active_test=False)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4761, in _where_calc
    e = expression.expression(cr, user, domain, self, context)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 646, in __init__
    self.parse(cr, uid, context=context)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 810, in parse
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field 'order_id.user_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('order_id.user_id', '=', 14) on purchase_order (ctx: )>"
```

Would you please advise?

Thank you,

Comment: *"it gives me error"*. And the error is....?

Comment: Thank you  Craig Ringer, I add the error to the question

Answer (score 1):

This error comes because of in *purhcase.order* object their is no field name `user_id.`

try with this,

```
['|',('order_id.validator','=',user.id),('order_id.validator','=',False)]
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you Odedra for your support again. I do have error when update the code and its mostly the same error `ValueError: Invalid field 'order_id.validator' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('order_id.validator', '=', 41) on purchase_order (ctx: )>"` Would you please advice?

Comment: can you show us how you write rule ? because at my end it's work fine

Comment: I just used *['|',('validator','=',user.id),('validator','=',False)]* and it works fine for me!